# What does the index of an UTXO stand for?

Tags: transactions, utxo, output

For example, here is the output of an API I hit with one of my testnet UTXOs. What is the meaning of the `index` field in this context ?

```
"utxo":[
    {
        "block_id":1899516,
        "transaction_hash":"14272c8d1be80d57f122ee336a7da655c1443cf6f95a7cfdfad2a1163b2d1247",
        "index":0,
        "value":1943034
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the position of your txo in the outputs array of the transaction that created it. You can see that [this transaction created 2 outputs](https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/14272c8d1be80d57f122ee336a7da655c1443cf6f95a7cfdfad2a1163b2d1247?expand) and that your output is the first one (`0`).
This index is also sometimes refer to as `vout`.